# Tengo un error en mi sintaxis declarando una clave foránea y el índex de la misma. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Al hacer la consulta, me da error de sintaxis en la linea 2 :C. Queria declarar la clave foranea y el index de la tabla "tonos_de_color" a "prductos"

```
   ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`tono_de_color` 
ADD INDEX `fk_idton_idx` (`idproductos` ASC) INVISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`tono_de_color` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_idton`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idproductos`)
  REFERENCES `inventario`.`productos` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Aiuda

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de MySQL? [Los índices `INVISIBLE` existen a partir de la versión 8](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-invisible-indexes/), este código no funcionará en versiones anteriores. Por otra parte, te sobra el punto y coma de la línea 3.

Comment: YA! Justo era eso, estaba en la version 8 (se supone), pero al eliminar INVISIBLE se ejecuto.

Comment: Si no funcionaba es porque no estabas en la versión 8. Me refiero a la versión de MySQL en sí misma (la base de datos) que no necesariamente tenga que ver con la versión de algún IDE. En algunos casos podrías tener incluso varias versiones, y estar conectando por defecto a la versión más antigua, desde un IDE en concreto, o porque tienes esa versión antigua por defecto en tu entorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa tu versión de MySQL. [Los índices INVISIBLE existen a partir de la versión 8](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-invisible-indexes/), este código no funcionará en versiones anteriores. Por otra parte, te sobra el punto y coma de la línea 3.

Asi debería funcionar en MySQL 8+:

```
ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`tono_de_color` 
    ADD INDEX `fk_idton_idx` (`idproductos` ASC) INVISIBLE;
    -- Este punto y coma sobra ;
```

Y en MySQL anterior a la versión:

```
ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`tono_de_color` 
    ADD INDEX `fk_idton_idx` (`idproductos` ASC);
```

Cuando hablo de **versión**, me refiero a la versión del servidor MySQL al que estés conectada, no tiene nada que ver necesariamente con versiones de IDEs como PHPMyAdmin, Workbench u otros, que son solamente interfaces para conectarte al servidor de MySQL.

Para saber con certeza la versión puedes ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
select version();
```

Obtendrás algo así o parecido en resultado:

```
version()
---------
8.0.27
```